# Is Rosh Hashana a remembrance or a day of remembrance?

Tags: words, prayer-book, rosh-hashanah-new-year

In the musaf for Rosh Hashana there are two options for marking the day. The Artscroll Machzor reads as follows:

ותתן לנו ה אלקינו באהבה את יום [השבת הזה ואת יום] הזכרון הזה

[on a weekday - יום / on the Sabbath זכרון]

תרועה

A simple read seems to point to the word "yom" ONLY on a weekday as the layout makes the two words a binary choice. Does this mean that on a Shabbat the "Yom Hazikaron" is, itself, "zichron t'ruah"? Or should the word "Yom" be placed in on both a weekday and a Shabbat making the Yom Hazikaron into a "Day of Zichron"?

The Machzor on [sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz%2C_Musaf%2C_First_Day_of_Rosh_Hashana%2C_Amidah?lang=bi) has the word "yom" present for all days. Are there varying discussions of whether the day is a remembrance or whether the day is a day OF remembrance?

Comment: @rosends "Yom" is only for weekdays. Many old editions were not as clear as artscroll in their layout leading to some misunderstandings of the practice.

Comment: @DoubleAA Even ArtScroll didn’t always lay it out so clearly. I have a 2002 edition of their machzor which simply has יום [זכרון] תרועה without indicating that יום isn’t said on shabbat.

Answer (score 3):

It’s worth nothing that the phrases ״yom teruah” and “zichron teruah” are both found in the Torah, in Bamidbar 29:1 and Vayikra 23:24 respectively. (The phrase “yom zichron teruah” does not appear anywhere in the Torah).

Both the Bavli (Rosh HaShanah 29b) and the Yerushalmi (Rosh HaShanah 4:1) link these two phrases to Rosh HaShanah during the week and on Shabbat, respectively.

Masechet Soferim 19:8 writes that if Rosh HaShanah falls on Shabbat, one says “zichron teruah” rather than “yom teruah”, since one does not generally blow the *shofar* on Shabbat.

This ruling is codified by Rosh (Rosh HaShanah 4:14), Tur (Orach Chaim 582) and Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 582:7).

So it’s clear that the text to be recited on Shabbat is “zichron teruah”.

As to what the phrase means, Rashi (Rosh HaShanah 29b) understands that it refers to us reading verses about the *shofar* rather than sounding the *shofar* itself.